# How to write a composite function of the form f(g(x))?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, discrete-mathematics

I wish to write a composite function of the form f(g(x)), where g(x) will be given as an input by the user and then for different x, f(g(x)) will be created as a vector so that they can be used as an input to other problems?

I wish this composite function to be inside another function which used values of f(g(x)) to calculate other stuffs.

Comment: What will be the `x` input?  Scalar?  array?  Array shape and dtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely idiomatic in Python (and a lot of other languages really), it works exactly as you'd want:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x+5
...
>>> def g(x):
...     return x*3
...
>>> f(g(5))  # (5*3) + 5
20
>>> f(g(4))  # (4*3) + 5
17
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> f(g(x))  # ([1, 2, 3, 4]*3) + 5
array([ 8, 11, 14, 17])
```

As long as the return values of the function `g` can be used as input to `f`, you're fine to do it just as you'd write it: `f(g(input))`.